# progress bar and requiredfieldvalidator

Tags: javascript, webforms, validation

I am using progressbar and required field validator. But when i click on the submit button. the progressbar and validator message both shown.
my code is

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function ShowDiv() {
        setTimeout('document.getElementById("PB").style.display = "inline";', 500); 
    }

</script>
...
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" ValidationGroup="ValGrpSave" onclick="btnSubmit_Click" OnClientClick="ShowDiv()" />
...
<asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail1" Width="350px" runat="server" />
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ValidationGroup="ValGrpSave" ErrorMessage="<b>Field Missing</b><br/>Issue no is Required" Display="None" ControlToValidate="txtEmail1" />
<cc1:ValidatorCalloutExtender ID="ValidatorCalloutExtender2" runat="server" TargetControlID="RequiredFieldValidator2" />
```

Comment: You will need more info than this. Please provide more.

Comment: this is a button : <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" ValidationGroup="ValGrpSave" onclick="btnSubmit_Click" OnClientClick="ShowDiv()"  />

Comment: this is the textbox control : <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail1" Width="350px" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                             <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ValidationGroup="ValGrpSave"
                       ErrorMessage="<b>Field Missing</b><br/>Issue no is Required" Display="None" ControlToValidate="txtEmail1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        <cc1:ValidatorCalloutExtender ID="ValidatorCalloutExtender2" runat="server" 
        TargetControlID="RequiredFieldValidator2">
    </cc1:ValidatorCalloutExtender>

Comment: Sumit, next time rather edit your original question with additional information than provide all this code in a comment. Ok? Otherwise we, the community, have to do it for you...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you don't prevent your button to start a form submit and since your form isn't valid, your validators display messages.

Try changing your script function to this if your button is only supposed to display progress bar (it is a different debate to change it non-server button instead since it doesn't have any server-side functionality but let's leave that to you):

```
function ShowDiv(evt) {

    // display progress bar after half a second
    setTimeout(function() {
         document.getElementById("PB").style.display = "inline";
    }, 500);

    // prevent button click event propagation thus prevent form submission
    evt.preventDefault();
    return false;
}
```

I've also changed `setTimeout` to prvide a function instead of the **deprecated** string statements.

And also make a change to your button

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" ValidationGroup="ValGrpSave" onclick="btnSubmit_Click" OnClientClick="return ShowDiv();" />
```

Comment: I am getting same problem here after change the code of javascript fuction

Comment: I am getting same problem here please suggest me what should i do

Comment: @SumitKumar: Can you please debug and check whether a postback to the server occurs? So we know where we are...

Comment: i checked the postback occurs

Comment: @SumitKumar: I've edited my answer with a tiny change to script and to the button control as well. Can you apply these changes and report back?